# SQL in PHP failure

Tags: php, mysql, sql

If the value of the result is 0 it has to go to 'cid_check_firstdep.php' otherways (if its 1) it has to go to 'cid_check_depwid.php'. 
It has to work, but i don't know why it doesn't. I've tried what i could that i think would be possible to fix it, but nono.
Code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  header('Location: /ucp/error.php');
  }

$sql = "SELECT validated FROM users WHERE username='".($_SESSION['username'])."'";
mysql_select_db("bluecard");
mysql_query($sql,$con);

if ($sql<'1')
    {
    mysql_close($con);
    header('Location: /ucp/cid_check_firstdep.php'); 
    }
else
    {
    mysql_close($con);
    header('Location: /ucp/cid_check_depwid.php');
    }
?>
```

or do i have to use :

```
 if ($sql=='0')
```

?

|||

@John Conde

```
<?php
if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
{
   $withdraw = addslashes ($_POST['withdraw']);

}
else
{
   $withdraw = $_POST['withdraw'];

}

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  header('Location: /ucp/error.php');
  }

$__sql = "SELECT cardvalue FROM users WHERE username='".($_SESSION['username'])."'";
mysql_select_db("bluecard");
mysql_query($__sql,$con);
if ($__sql<'5000000')
    {
    header('Location: /ucp/includes/withdraw_fail.php'); 
    mysql_close($con);
    }
else
    {

    $_sql = "UPDATE users SET Bank=Bank + '$deposit' WHERE Username='".($_SESSION['username'])."'";
mysql_select_db("server");
    mysql_query($_sql,$con);
$sql = "UPDATE users SET cardvalue=cardvalue +- '$deposit', thismonth_withdraw=thismonth_withdraw + '$deposit', lastwithdraw = Now() WHERE username='".($_SESSION['username'])."'";
mysql_select_db("bluecard");
mysql_query($sql,$con);
mysql_close($con);
header('Location: /ucp/includes/withdraw_done.php');
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're checking the wrong variable for your SQL result. You're using the variable containing your query instead of the variable you never assigned to capture the result of `mysql_query()`. You also want to use `mysql_num_rows()` to see how many results were returned.:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);

if ($result && mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
```

FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Hmm not really working. Instead this script is totally working :
EDIT. I have put it in the post, its messing up the code in the comment.

Comment: You didn't even use the code I posted. Why do you thnk your code would suddenly start working if you didn't fix it?

Comment: Oh wait i dont try how many results came back, i try to see if that result, it would be always only 1 result. If its value is 0 then .. else ..

Answer (score 0):

Hi Morgan I change your code according to my knowledge. I think this will help you to work done.

If you found any match to the username "count($return_data)" will get 1.

Thanks.

```
 <?php
    $con         = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
    $select_db   = mysql_select_db("bluecard");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      header('Location: /ucp/error.php');
      }

    $sql = "SELECT validated FROM users WHERE username='".($_SESSION['username'])."'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql,$con);
    $return_data = array();
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $return_data[]=$rows;   
    }

    if (count($return_data)<=1)
        {
        mysql_close($con);
        header('Location: /ucp/cid_check_firstdep.php'); 
        }
    else
        {
        mysql_close($con);
        header('Location: /ucp/cid_check_depwid.php');
        }
    ?>
```